Why does my POSCAR file say I have 4 Pd atoms when I actually have 14 based on my structure from a crystal database?
I am having trouble getting my geometry optimization to run, and I think it may be my POSCAR.
I downloaded a FCC Pd crystal structure from a crystal database. I downloaded the cif into materials studio and then put it into vesta to get my POSCAR.
Even though I did this my POCASR structure has a 4 under the Pd atom sign even though there should be 14. I think it has something to do with symmetry, but I thought in order to run a VASP optimization I need every Atoms location. I was wondering how to get the location of all 14 or if I don't there may be something else going wrong that I am not aware of. ** (See bottom of post to see that the number of atoms does not seem to be the problem)
To follow this my issue says:
WARNING: Sub-Space-Matrix is not hermitian in DAV

and
ERROR FEXCP: supplied Exchange-correletion table
    is too small, maximal index :       27483

I saw other StackExchange posts saying it may be my structure hence the question. But if it is not what else could it be. I have attached the INCAR file as well. I have tried a large POTIM of 0.05 and a smaller one of 0.01 already. I have also tried an IBRION= 1, 2 and 3, to explore the various relaxations.
INCAR

System = Pd structure

PREC  = ACCURATE

ISTART = 0 

ICHARG = 2 

ENCUT = 500

ISMEAR = 1

SIGMA = 0.09

EDIFF = 1E-5

EDIFFG = -0.05

NELM = 100

NELMIN = 2

NSW = 400

ALGO = FAST

IBRION = 3 

ISIF = 2

POTIM = 0.025 #step size

MAXMIX=12  #reuse the mixer between ionic steps; save time

ISPIN = 1

GGA = PE #Perdew-Burke-Ernzerof

IVDW = 12 #Dispersion: D3-BJ

LWAVE = .FALSE.

LCHARG = .FALSE.

NCORE = 64


POSCAR

Pd Crystal
1.0
     3.9579999447         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
     0.0000000000         3.9579999447         0.0000000000
     0.0000000000         0.0000000000         3.9579999447
   Pd
   4
Direct
     0.000000000         0.000000000         0.000000000
     0.000000000         0.500000000         0.500000000
     0.500000000         0.000000000         0.500000000
     0.500000000         0.500000000         0.000000000


Some more updates on my issue,
I figured out how to get all my atoms written (all 14) in VESTA when creating my POSCAR. Which now I know does not solve the problem, and just creates a new one.
 VERY BAD NEWS! internal error in subroutine LATTYP:
 Cellvolume is zero !      -3

This issue is known to be about more than one atom having the same coordinates (because of symmetry). So now I at least know it's not my POSCAR (most likely) and might be stemming from another issue.

Welcome! The INCAR is helpful, but at first glance I cannot tell if it is problematic. It would help if you either included the POSCAR or a way to reproduce generating it.

I went ahead and edited the post adding in my POSCAR. I got the initial structure from a crystal database (https://qiserver.ugr.es/cod/1011108.html)

+1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future. Can you please provide the INCAR and POSCAR in text format rather than a screenshot?

Okay! I have added the INCAR as a text and the POSCAR as text but in a code block since it reads easier for me. Let me know if there is anything else I can provide, or if I added something wrong!

Perhaps you can self-answer your original question and ask the new one in a new post?

Okay I will, thanks for the help so far on formatting my questions!

To render the question more reproducible, add the name of the database accessed and e.g., ICSD/COD number.  E.g., obabel's conversion of COD 9008478 yields 1 below the symbol Pd.

I figured out how to get all my atoms written (all 14) in VESTA when creating my POSCAR. Which now I know does not solve the problem, and just creates a new one. But in order to list all your atoms when you export your POSCAR from VESTA click the drop down under the fractional or cartesian selection and select "Output coordinates of all displayed atoms". This forces it to diplay atoms that would not be considered due to symmetry. However, this causes a new issue if you do have symmetry seen below.
VERY BAD NEWS! internal error in subroutine LATTYP:
Cellvolume is zero !      -3

This issue is known to be about more than one atom having the same coordinates (because of symmetry). So now I at least know it's not my POSCAR (most likely) and might be stemming from another issue.
